# Visual Studio git error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" after checking out another branch

Tags: visual-studio

I can't check out another branches then the Git Changes interface gave me an error "O**bject reference not set to an instance of an object**."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are some files to commit before checking out another branch. Adding these file by command **git add .** in command line interface

Comment: It looks like the same person created 2 profiles one for the question and one for the answer. The question is not clear much but, the answer is readily accepted.

Answer (score 0):

### I've seen this error when trying to work with an empty Git repository in Visual Studio.

Specifically, when trying to check out the URL of a freshly created repository with no commits at all in it. The project that results from this can scan the repository for any later changes but encounters the "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error whenever it tries to check out a branch.

I haven't found a way to correct it in place, but what worked as a workaround was **deleting the Visual Studio project and using another Git client to make any commit at all to the empty repository**. Even just a README.txt file is enough to establish a master branch, and from then on Visual Studio can check out the repository into a new project, which can create new branches without encountering this error.